# Mysql: Best practice to extract not linked data in multiTable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'M using a large select into a multi table where i have many rows i need to tell you that no table is linked. I need to extract each one and add into an array.

My problem is:

When I use this:

```
mysql> select w.*,s.*,p.*,h.*,c.*,b.*,o.* from
       `base` b,`chain` c,`house` h,
       `option` o,`piece` p,systems s,
       `wall` w;
```

Sometimes, I got this after execution query:

`ERROR 2008 (HY000): MySQL client ran out of memory`

It take about 1minutes to execute this function and something like 1min40 for the fetch array result.

And after that, i need to use something like:

```
$base = $chain =
$house = $option=
$piece= $systems =
$wall = array();
while($row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    //build all array properly
}
```

it is possible to reduce time execution? It is better to use 1 query for each table I need to extract and push row into the "good" array?

Thanks

** **EDIT** **

I also tried this but samething:

```
mysql> select w.*,s.*,p.*,h.*,c.*,b.*,o.* from
       `base` b INNER JOIN `chain` c INNER JOIN `house` h INNER JOIN 
       `option` o INNER JOIN `piece` p INNER JOIN systems s INNER JOIN 
       `wall` w;
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get all of the data from each of those tables or is there a good reason you're using a cartesian join?

Comment: Sorry, I want to get Table 1 put into the array 1, all rows, all collumns, table 2 into the array 2... etc.. I'm not sure if call 7 or 8 times a query is a a better practice or I need to minimize it.. But My current SQL use alot of memory and take times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a query for each table.

The query you mention does a cartesian join which is almost certainly not what you want.  In a cartesian join, each row will have data from each table and the total rows will be the product of the total rows of each table (i.e. if each table has 10 rows, the query will return 10,000,000 rows).  The script runs out of memory because your query fetches many times more data than you're actually interested in or using.

Using a single query for each table only fetches the data you want and should work and be much faster.

Comment: yes! true!. thanks for your answer! I need to `$data->free();` after each query? or if I override `$data` I can do after all?

Comment: You don't need to call `free()` after each query.  It will get cleaned up automatically when there are no references to the data.  If you overwrite `$data` for each query, that will do it otherwise you can `unset()` the variables when you're done with them, but you probably shouldn't _need_ to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use join in from statement or join in where statement the mysql is make all variation from these tables rows, and this leads to memory corruptions! 
If you joined these tables then you don't get error message.

Comment: but I don't have an `ID_object` to link table So I can't use `"ON"` thats ok too?

Comment: then you can query for one at a time down the tables